# Why do we need to store Goefence data in android app?

Tags: android, android-geofence

My question is self descriptive,I've read a lot about how to use **Geofence Api** in android App.
I follow so many tutorials and even links from SO.I'm developing an application which uses Geofencing.But still there's one question that i'm not clear about is why we need to store Geofence circle in persistent storage.
From [official developers site](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)  it says that:

**Define geofence storage**

```
A geofencing app needs to read and write geofence data to persistent storage.You 
shouldn't use Geofence objects to do this; instead, use storage techniques such as
databases that can store groups of related data.
```

As from my understanding LocationClient is used to register geofence and same for removing it,also it triggers the notification based on the location where we are not even accessing storage to trigger notification for events.**So why do we need to store it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from what they say in the documentation, there is no hard requirement for persisting geofences. If you're okay with loosing your geofences after say a device reboot or creating your fences on the fly, then you're good to go without persisting them.